# Laravel Count > Other Count

Tags: laravel

I have the next question:

I have the next table on mysql

```
ID | IDPAYMENT | CUSTOMER | PAYDATE     | STATUS    |  PENDINGAMOUNT | PAYTO DATE
1  |    1      |   JOHN   |  2018-12-15 |  PAYED    |    $0          | 2018-11-01
2  |    1      |   JOHN   |    NO/PAY   |  PENDING  |    $10         | 2018-11-15   
3  |    1      |   JOHN   |    NO/PAY   |  PENDING  |    $10         | 2018-12-01   
4  |    1      |   JOHN   |    NO/PAY   |  PENDING  |    $10         | 2018-12-15   
5  |    1      |   JOHN   |    NO/PAY   |  PENDING  |    $10         | 2019-01-01   
6  |    1      |   JOHN   |    NO/PAY   |  PENDING  |    $10         | 2018-01-15  
7  |    1      |   JOHN   |    NO/PAY   |  PENDING  |    $10         | 2018-02-01
```

I want to count status with PENDING and compare with count of ID:

STATUS  PENDING = 6

ID COUNT        = 7

The idea is to SUM the PENDINGAMOUNT where the Status = Pending, and the date is < to today to add a commission for No Payment...

Answer (score 0):

For :

> SUM the PENDINGAMOUNT where the Status = Pending, and the date is < to today ...

Raw SQL :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE `status` = 'PENDING` AND `paydate` < CURDATE()
```

Converting to laravel builder :

```
$count = Model::where('status', 'PENDING')->whereDate('paydate', '<', Carbon::today())->count();
```

Getting total count of all rows :

```
$totalCount = Model::count();
```

Not sure about adding commission as we will need more business logic for the same.